# Same material, different result

Tags: materials

After finishing the material (see middle) I applied it to the other objects next to it, but they don't "react", I have have tried the scale/UV Map stuff, without success, but it seems more like a bug from Blender or maybe my GPU is the problem ?

Blender version : 4.0
GPU : RTX 4070 Ti.
OS : Windows 11
CPU : i5 12400

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you suspect that it is a hardware bug, maybe it is best to share the file, and whoever is available will test it. In the meantime, try to switch the rendering device between CPU and GPU. You may also want to go to the settings under *System* and configure the *Cycles Render Devices*.

Comment: Maybe it's intentional, but is it ok that the Mix Shader node is not connected to the material output?

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact objects that you have in your scene I can just guess. But as @joshsanfelici already commented, the *Mix Shader* is not connected, so the only thing the material outputs is a *Glass BSDF* with an either completely smooth or completely rough surface... the *Pointiness* information with the *Color Ramp*.

First of all, to make the *Pointiness* work correctly, you need a dense mesh (I cannot see your meshes in the question) and even then it only works in Cycles. Otherwise the complete object will get a uniform color/value which is what happens here, I guess.

Now, but even then, why are they different? The pointiness of edges - or the uniform value the mesh gets in this case - and therefore the threshold when the roughness switches from smooth to rough depends on the different objects. I used slightly different objects and *Color Ramp* settings then you, but basically it is like in my example, here I have a cube and a kind of crystal, same material but the cube is rough and the crystal is smooth:

[image: different look]

Moving the *Color Ramp* sliders a bit to the left makes both objects rough:

[image: both rough]

Now moving them to the right, suddenly both objects look smooth:

[image: both smmooth]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to each and everyone who took the time to help me. By the time I realized that my question has been answered I have solved the issue by disconnecting the Color Ramp from the Glass BSDF that can be seen in the second screenshot I posted.